# How to get downloadurl of an image in google drive using python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I need to get downloadurl of an image that is in google drive. I have seen the post [Downloading Images from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423157/downloading-images-from-google-drive) but could not be clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='downloadUrl').execute()
print file['downloadUrl']
```

Comment: how do i get fileid for an image file?